# Synaptics: Enable 2-finger flick instead of 3-finger flick?

Tags: windows-8, synaptics-touchpad

Is there a way to use the old 2-finger flick (swipe) instead of the new 3-finger flick with the newest Windows 8.1 driver? (17.0.19)

3-finger flick feels really unintuitive to me, because I only have 2 fingers on the touchpad when I'm scrolling. Also 3-finger flick fails more often, because it's harder to have 3 fingers on the touchpad at the same time than only 2 and sometimes 1 of the fingers isn't properly registered. Maybe there's a hidden registry setting or something for that?